# Python Program Doesn't Execute Any Functions

Tags: python, function, primes

I'm currently learning python for fun. I'm used to coding in C++ and so far it's fairly easy to pickup. I wrote my first program on my own, but for some reason, it doesn't do anything and the functions I wrote won't execute. If I write print statements outside the functions, the statements execute, but it never goes inside the function. Here is my code. Any tips would be much appreciated.

```
racks = 1000000
sum = 0
def ConsecutivePrime():
    primeNum = 0
    stack = []
    while(StackAdder == False):
        primeNum = isPrime(primeNum)
        stack.append(primeNum)
        StackAdder(stack)
    if(StackAdder == True):
        print ("Largets Prime: ", sum)

def StackAdder(stack):
    for n in stack:
        sum += n 
    if(count < racks):
        return False
    else:
        stack.pop()
        return True

def isPrime(primeNum):
    isPrime = False
    while(isPrime == False):
        primeNum += 1 
        if(primeNum % 2 == 1): #First Checks If Odd 
            if(primeNum % 3 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            elif(primeNum % 5 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            elif(primeNum % 7 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            elif(primeNum % 9 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            else:
                isPrime == True
    if(isPrime == True):
        return primeNum

def main():
    ConsecutivePrime()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: How are you executing the python script?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in ConsecutivePrime. Trace through one line at a time. Watch what happens when it hits the "while (StackAdder ... " line.

Comment: Also, FWIW, It is not idiomatic to see "if x == True".  In python, you'd generally just write `if x: ...`

Answer (score 3):

`StackAdder` is a function; it is neither `True` nor `False`, so `ConsecutivePrime` *is* called, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: I don't agree. Functions evaluate to true: `bool(myFunction)`

Comment: *Calling* the function might; the function itself, not so much.

Comment: Then check it out your own. Define a function and then put it inside a condition or try with the `bool` function

Comment: Which does not obviously mean that the function is called.

Comment: Function pointers are truthy, but I assume that's not what OP is trying to check.

Comment: I think you are confusing the concepts of `True` and *truthy*.

Comment: I did not say the function was true, but that it _evaluated_ to true (truthy, as @MorganThrapp says). I know the OP is not asking that, but I am just clearing it out so that he doesn't confuse.

Comment: @J.C.Rocamonde: By your logic, integers also evaluate to `True`; for example, `bool(3)`.

Comment: >>> def a():
 print "A"
,
>>> a == True -> False ,
>>> bool(a) -> True

Comment: Functions do not evaluate to `True`; they can be used in expressions that do.  They *are*, however, *truthy*.  And integers do *not* evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines at the beginning of your `ConsecutivePrime()` function, and observe the output:

```
print(StackAdder == True)
print(StackAdder == False)
```

You can see `False` printed twice, right? Surprised? Read the comments on the answer by Scott Hunter. May be that will help a little.

So, your conditionals for both `while` and `if` are False.

If what you wanted was to check what value `StackAdder()` returned, you need to do it like this:

```
def ConsecutivePrime():
    primeNum = 0
    stack = []
    while(StackAdder(myStack) == False): # define myStack to your needs
        primeNum = isPrime(primeNum)
        stack.append(primeNum)
        StackAdder(stack)
    if(StackAdder(myStack) == True):
        print ("Largets Prime: ", sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are major problems in the way you structured your code, and I will try to point out the most obvious mistakes in your functions:

1) Regarding the function `isPrime(primeNum)`, this is the correct way of writing it:

```
def isPrime(primeNum):
    isPrime = False
    while not isPrime:
        primeNum += 1 
        if(primeNum % 2 == 1): #First Checks If Odd 
            if(primeNum % 3 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            elif(primeNum % 5 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            elif(primeNum % 7 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            elif(primeNum % 9 == 0):
                isPrime == False
            else:
                isPrime == True
    return primeNum
```

I rewrote `while(isPrime == False)` as `while not isPrime`. Also, you don't need the `if(isPrime == True)` statement, because the while loop will be exited when `isPrime == True`.

2) In the function `StackAdder(stack)`, you are introducing `count`, which was not defined before. Maybe you wanted `sum` instead? Or maybe you were trying to use the `count()` method (which returns the count of how many times an obj occurs in a list?)

3) In the function `ConsecutivePrime()`, `Stackadder` is a function, so your code should be: `while(StackAdder(stack) == False)`